# Return int as boolean

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, aapt

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I decompiled the source code of a professional application. When I copied the source code into eclipse, an error came up with the following code( the error is with the return type):

```
public boolean method(){
...
...
   for(int i = 0; ; i = 1){
       return i;
}
```

How can I change the code to keep it correct but keep the functionality?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The OP may have asked a very elementary question. Do we really want to punish young coders who are still learning?

Comment: The application looks very professional.

Comment: Most noobish question with professional and encouraging answers...

Do not downvote, let him learn...

Comment: Learn... From decomp.... You must be kiding ...

Comment: Sorry, if he's a beginner he should be reading the for loop documentation, not rewriting stupidly written methods to keep the outcomes. LEARN HERE: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html Then he won't even need to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Don't try and base any of you code on this 'professional' application, as the author must have been a professional idiot.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast `i` as a `boolean`, or change `return i;` to `return i != 0;`, which will be true for all non-zero values of `i`, and false if `i == 0`.

As a side note, I really see *no reason* to wrap a `return` in a `for` loop. In this case, you might as well just replace both of those lines with `return 0;` (or `return false;`, to match the method signature).

Comment: ... hence the downvotes. That's why Selvin and me warned about the catch in the question. I seriously doubt this was a honest question (a beginner that decompiles stuff to analyze a for loop? and doesn't even read about for loop?). To me it's more like someone trying to prank people.

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type from `boolean` to `int`.

As you can see, your method is returning `i` which is declared as an `int` in the `for` loop, so the return type of your method has to be the same as the type of the variable it returns.

Comment: Ok, ok ... But this loop has no sens  and it just means return 0